# Get channel ID after joining via a private or public invite link and forward messages

Tags: python, telethon

I try to do 2 things

1. get Channel ID [is always an integer -100xxxxx...) when I join from invite link
2. Forward files of channel to my private channel

```
    from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
    from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest
    from telethon.tl.types import KeyboardButtonCallback
    from telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist import BotResponseTimeoutError
    import asyncio
    import logging
    import re
    from telethon import events
    from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
    from telethon.errors import UserAlreadyParticipantError
```

I try to do in this way, relevant code is this

```
        # Extract the link from the message text
        link = re.search("(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", event.text)
        if link:
            link = link.group("url")
            print(f"Link: {link}")

            # Extract the invitation code from the link
            invite_code = link.split('/')[-1]

            try:
                # Join the channel or group
                updates = await client(ImportChatInviteRequest(invite_code))
            except UserAlreadyParticipantError:
                print("Already joined the channel or group.")
                return

            # Define invite_link
            invite_link = link

            # Get the ID of the channel or group you just joined
            channel = await client.get_entity(invite_link)
            print(channel.id)

            # Wait a while before getting messages from the channel or group
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

            # Get messages from the channel or group
            messages = await client.get_messages(channel.id, limit=100, include_media=True)  # Get the last 100 messages

            # Print the text of each message and forward the messages to your chat
            for message in messages:
                print(message.text)
                if message.media:
                    print("This message contains media.")
                await client.forward_messages('-10016********', message, channel.id)

            # Forward all messages to your chat
            await client.forward_messages('-10016********', messages, channel.id)
```

Example of invite links, public and private

```
https://t.me/joinchat/TqPg*****
https://t.me/+U_jA*****
```

But I can't get channel ID for public invite links after joined to chat because I get this error "`Already joined the channel or group."`
Instead, for private invite links I have problems to join to chat using Telethon library

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 570, in _dispatch_update
    await callback(event)
  File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\SCRIPT\29_metalarea2_estrazioni\extra_bot.py", line 99, in handle_edited_message
    updates = await client(ImportChatInviteRequest(invite_code))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 87, in _call
    result = await future
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.InviteHashExpiredError: The chat the user tried to join has expired and is not valid anymore (caused by ImportChatInviteRequest)
```